# Why is aluminium body considered better than magnesium?

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-x100

The recently announced Fuji X100V touts aluminium construction over previously used magnesium  as a benefit, what are the claimed advantages of aluminium over magnesium ?

Comment: Those are elements. It is almost undoubtedly made from alloys. Which ones?

Comment: @Mazura ones that are either made mainly of aluiminium or from magnesium.

Answer (score 14):

They are touting that the parts are CNC milled from billet aluminum compared to cast magnesium as is commonly used. Both are alloys and probably contain some of the other in their mix.

In general, if you compared identical parts; one milled from billet and one cast from the same material, the billet part will be stronger.
But that is not the comparison. Magnesium alloys are both lighter and stronger, particularly in thin wall construction. It is also less prone to corrosion.

I agree with Michael... it's probably just hype. In this case, besides being a somewhat cheaper material, it also has much lower initial production costs. Programming a CNC mill is a lot quicker and cheaper than creating high precision molds. There is a lot less risk compared to machining magnesium (the cast parts are still machined/finished). And it's also a lot cheaper to change/abandon in two years when it's time for the next "upgrade."

TBH, I think it was a smart move. But no real benefit to the end user (unless some cost savings are passed along?).

FWIW, the Sigma fp is being [milled from billet magnesium](https://www.imaging-resource.com/news/2019/10/01/sigma-factory-tour-update-magnesium-sigma-fp-camera-body)...

Comment: I agree with you but, it does seem odd that they'd hype this change as opposed to make an attempt to silently sweep it under the rug...

Comment: Milling aluminum isn't very cheap because it takes a lot of time and a lot of material is wasted.

Comment: @Hueco They had to hype *something*...

Comment: @Orbit, have you ever priced high precision molds? They easily cost 10's of thousands. And the machining waste is recycled to recoup some of the cost.

Comment: @StevenKersting: I don't think that is much compared to the total cost of setting up a production line. I don't disagree with your arguments, it is cheaper to set up and less risk, but I don't think it is much cheaper overall.

Comment: @Orbit You don't need to setup a new production line if you're just doing the same CNC jobs. That's one of the reasons CNCs are preferred for short production runs - casting can be much cheaper per item, but the initial costs are very high. None of the material you mill away is wasted, the recycling is trivial - all that you waste is the energy you would need to melt the material for casting in the first place (and obviously, less of it, since you don't melt the whole thing, just the shavings).

Comment: @Luaan: I know. But 1. camera's are usually not produced in short production runs, it's generally 100.000's or millions (except for some Leica or Phase One camera's maybe) 2. Camera companies usually don't cast their own aluminum, they buy blocks and get at best 20 to 30% of the purchase price back for scraps. Thats why I say that it is not necessarily cheaper to mill aluminum.

Comment: @Luaan You also use time on your million dollar cnc mill. Some parts will wear out and you need to amortize the purchase price.

Answer (score 11):

The main advantage of aluminum over magnesium alloy:

It's cheaper for the manufacturer to buy.

Comment: Also, less flammable :) Not good, though, if you want to scrape a bit of camera corner off to make emergency flash powder :)

Comment: If your camera catching fire is a *normal* problem for you, I'd suggest blaming shooting habits, and not the camera... ;)

Comment: @rackandboneman That's probably why they use magnesium *alloy* instead of elemental magnesium (which, as we all should know, would not survive the time it took to ship from the parts plant to the camera factory if unprotected from the moisture in the air).

Comment: >Actually, it is much more difficult to ignite magnesium chips and dust than is usually supposed, and for that reason they do not present great machining difficulties. The special techniques that must be used in fabricating magnesium (working, casting, and joining) add considerably to the manufacturing cost. In selecting between aluminium and magnesium or a given part, the base cost of the metal may not give much advantage to either, but usually the manufacturing operations make magnesium more expensive. – [Magnesium alloy,  Machining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_alloy#Machining)

Comment: @Mazura You're talking about magnesium alloy. Elemental magnesium , as a group II element, will form oxides when exposed to oxygen, nitrogen, and hydrogen. If the temperature is high enough, it will react with water. Once it is burning, exposing it to water will only make it burn more violently as the reaction between magnesium and steam releases hydrogen gas.

Comment: Of course we're talking about alloys; you said "alloy". And to go any further we need to know which ones. "touts aluminium [alloy] construction over previously used magnesium [alloy]" - w/o knowing specifics all we can say is that, generally, magnesium costs more *to work*. - "considered better" by who? *Them.*

Comment: It costs more per kg to *buy*. Although magnesium is about twice as expensive as aluminium, its hot-chamber die-casting process is easier, more economical, and 40% to 50% faster than cold-chamber process required for aluminium. "Considered better" by *Fuji's ad copy*.

Comment: @MichaelC even elemental magnesium is surprisingly tame. It will form an (ugly) oxide layer rapidly in air, but after that its basically passive. It typically takes a fair bit of grinding, shaving, and heat to get a piece to light up.

Comment: @mbrig That ugly layer of tarnish is enough to make it unpaintable without the added expense of removing the tarnish first (and hoping the dimensions are still within tolerance).